# Encryption of syslog & auditd in local disk?

Tags: encryption, syslog, rsyslog, audit

We need to use encrypted `syslog` and `auditd` in local disk.

**Is it possible to save syslog and auditd message encrypted in disk ?**

Comment: Yes? What is the problem?

Comment: What level of encryption are you looking for? SED works for some use cases. LUKS might fit your requirements. Best bet for many cases is a restricted centralized server with encrypted disks.

Comment: Encrypted real-time to those logs? Or encrypted at rest?

Comment: Encrypted realtime.

Comment: Can anyone please describe how encryption is done? Thx

Answer (score 2):

rsyslogd can encrypt when writing to a logfile. For example,

```
action(type="omfile" file="mylog" cry.provider="gcry" cry.keyfile="mykeyfile")
```

Put the key in `mykeyfile`. The default algorithm AES128 uses a key of exactly 16 characters, so for example do

```
printf "%-16.16s" mykeyissixteenchars >mykeyfile
```

To read the `mylog` file use

```
rscryutil --keyfile mykeyfile mylog
```

This utility comes with rsyslog, though may be in a separate package. See the [doc](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/cryprov_gcry.html).